# Winform, authorization on ui

Tags: c#, winforms, authorization

0  vote down check

I'm thinking on creating standard users, roles, permissions table schema, add contorls table and permission would be 'for a role on a control' and then in form loading event fire up a method to set Enabled proprerty of controls due to user's role's permissions. Is this good idea or i should took a hammer and get this out of my head (and if i should, please tell me why ;) )

Comment: Could be, but also make sure you do authorization on data acces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I probably would advise against the individual control roles table and just deal with setting the states of the controls in the application based on what Role the user has.

e.g.

```
Button adminButton = new Button();
Button userButton = new Button();
...

public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User user = // find user
    adminButton.Enabled = (user.Role == UserRoles.Admin)
    userButton.Enabled = (user.Role == UserRoles.Admin || user.Role == UserRoles.Standard)
}
```

Other than that, it seems a normal approach.

Comment: i can't hardcode this like you suggest, becouse permissions have to be managable (i should be able to change through user firendly interface)

Comment: If every control you  have MUST be configurable i.e. unable to group them, then using a control table would be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a similar schema, works out reasonably well. Allows for fine-grained control; but it's also a lot of work to get all permissions right.